# Does Android Things support plugins?

Tags: android, android-things

I am working on a project for Android Things, and I realised I don't quite know if it will work out, because of the whole, parititioning and images setup they have. Does anyone know if letting my product download apk with new features, (to support new devices being attached)  from a specific site, and install them is A) Doable, B) likely to break the update system

Comment: Why you need "plugin", if you can install/update `.apk`? Do you read [this](https://developer.android.com/things/console/update)?

Comment: I don't mean an update, I mean I want to make a product that can support multiple smart home devices, I was hoping that instead of having to update to add compatibility each time a new product comes out, I could make a downloadable library my product downloads from my server and loads

Comment: Android Things is Android, so you can create plugin architecture like [this](http://androidsrc.net/creating-android-app-plugin-architecture-tutorial/) or [that](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/05/31/android-plugin-application.aspx), but IMHO it's too complex compared to update whole `.apk`.

Comment: Apparently there is problems installing new apk's on Android Things, which is why I didn't want to go the whole new apk route like those two plugin routes do

Comment: Anyway "plugins" should be an `.apk`.